# Split UL elements to responsible columns

Tags: css, grid, html-lists, multiple-columns

Is's my first post so please forgive me my mistakes :P

I would like make list split into few columns like on those websites:

http://www.maxmodels.pl/

http://themecloud.co/ - there are couple of similiar themes

So far I make some code: http://jsfiddle.net/cfUqc/2/

```
ul{
  width:760px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
li{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
#double li  { width:45%;} 
#triple li  { width:30.333%; } 
#quad li    { width:25%; } 
#six li     { width:16.666%; }
```

but i have empty spaces between horizontal elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying to achieve the effect that I believe you are after I would look at using the masonry library http://masonry.desandro.com. if this does not give you exactly what you are after There are many other clone projects available